# Deleting a repository from linux

Tags: linux, fedora

I am new to linux and have been using fedora for a month or 2. I was installing sublime text and came across a tutorial that ended up not working. However, it left this repository on my system that was required for the tutorial of installing sublime text (that i eneded up not going with, but did try it). Now when I try and install anything the system errors due to this. I have an image where I simply try to install xchat for IRC. This pasted text from my terminal can speak for anything I try to install, as this is the same error I get everytime. Its the "cloudhike" repo lines. It gets to them and just stops. I tried all the research and couldn't find any solutions already.

** from my terminal:

[root@localhost username]# su -c 'yum install xchat'
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
google-chrome                                            |  951 B     00:00
rpmfusion-free-updates                                   | 3.3 kB     00:00
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates                                | 3.3 kB     00:00
http://repo.cloudhike.com/sublime2/fedora/19/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from sublime2: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://repo.cloudhike.com/sublime2/fedora/19/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[root@localhost username]#

Comment: I always feel so un-welcomed at this website. I try to use it but something like this always happens...I think it should be a private website instead of just wishing it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just disable the `yum` repo. It's as simple as that. You can do this with the command:

```
yum-config-manager --disable http://repo.cloudhike.com/sublime2/fedora/sublime2.repo
```

[This page](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html) has more infomration.

Also, the reason this happened is that you are using Fedora 19, while the repo only supports up to Fedora 18.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I use the suggested command you provided I get this:[root@localhost ~]# yum-config-manager --disable http://repo.cloudhike.com/sublime2/fedora/sublime2.repo
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
[root@localhost ~]# 
and I still get the same error when trying to install programs

Comment: Odd. Can you try running `sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/sublime2.repo`? Check [this link](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/yum-remove-repo-repository-yum-disable-repo-repository/).